# Marxism related question

Tags: discussion

---

In my present understanding: Marxism consists of three aspects: Philosophy, Political Economy, Scientific socialism.

And many questions are interweaved with each other closely. Some examples of Political Economy are used to exemplify Philosophy Principles.

[here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/7723/could-there-be-revolutions-in-socialist-countries) is my first question, I see some comments say that something is off-topic.

So, are questions about Marxism(I think it is philosophy) accepted here.

What's your opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Good question. The line can be hazy sometimes, but the general rule I've been following is that typically a topic is considered valid for Philosophy.SE if you can find it (or an umbrella issue pertaining to it) in your average introductory textbook on Philosophy. Marxist philosophy is fine, but I think is talking about it's applications in the real world, which is not about the concept of Marxism itself *per se* but how that concept applies in current day situations. This move, while not always bad, does seem to push your question more off-topic for this site and perhaps a better fit for [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).